# How to modify the columns to geometric points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, gps

How make points geometric if already exist columns with data like column names are gps_latitued and gps_longititude  in mapping table

Comment: You mean like `SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(gps_longititude, gps_latitued),4326);` ?

Comment: yes for that columns datatype is numeric but i want make it GEOGRAPHY  and  find the points  with center point long and lat with some radius (ex:50KM)

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html